# How to save Plotchart canvas other than PostScript without displaying it?

Tags: user-interface, charts, tcl, tk-toolkit

I read the section [OTHER OUTPUT FORMATS](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/plotchart.html#SECTid82631b0) of [Plotchart](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/plotchart.html) documentation, but still can't figure out how to do it.

I want to:

1. Save canvas as image without displaying it. So I can run it in batch mode.
2. Save in other format. (ex: jpeg, png...)

A brief example is appreciated.

Comment: That section of the documentation is really hard to make use of, requiring deep knowledge of image formats *and* the plotchart implementation. I guess it to be of use to an expert who wants to make an SVG exporter, but not a PNG exporter. (Plots shouldn't be turned into JPGs at all; that's a format that only works well for actual photographs.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [Img](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1404) library is capable to converts Postscript into various formats, and a quick and dirty way do **not display** the canvas is to run `exit` immediately.

Here is an example:

```
package require Plotchart
package require Img

canvas .c -background white -width 400 -height 200
pack   .c -fill both

set s [::Plotchart::createXYPlot .c {0.0 100.0 10.0} {0.0 100.0 20.0}]

foreach {x y} {0.0 32.0 10.0 50.0 25.0 60.0 78.0 11.0 } {
    $s plot series1 $x $y
}

$s title "Data series"

set file "test.ps"
$s saveplot $file
set root [file rootname $file]

set image [image create photo -file $file]
foreach {f suffix} {JPEG jpg GIF gif PNG png} {
    $image write $root.$suffix -format $f
}

exit
```

Comment: There are also external tools which can do the transformation from postscript (really encapsulated postscript) to various image formats. (I think there's something in imagemagick for that sort of thing.)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try this solution, but the man page you linked describes a `saveplot` command to store the plot into a Postscript (or other image format) file.

Once you created your plot widget, you can do something like

```
.plot saveplot filename.ps -plotregion bbox
```

where the `-plotregion bbox` says to save all the plot and not just the visible part (`-plotregion window`, which is the default).

Comment: i tried `saveplot` to generate results in postscript format, but didn't know how to do this without displaying the canvas