# dealing with canvas copy trouble in tcl

Tags: canvas, tcl, clipboard, file-conversion

I created with `Plotchart::createLogXYPlot` in the canvas.
I'm drawing several Graph in same canvas. (Using several plot in same canvas)
I need this canvas to copy or convert file format type.
But I'm searching about this topic, didn't help for me.

Main trouble is saved file having a clipping img.

Clipboard canvas is not working for me. (can't find tag about plotchart)

I'm trying these ways.

1. capturing canvas to img file format (clipping trouble)

   https://nikit.tcl-lang.org/page/Img#2155d00fdc05c6b6b85fa38ed5cd7dda67fd680886245dd51b6f9bcc0ba05a5c
2. Snapshot canvas (clipping trouble and spend many time)

   https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.tcl/Dweb1ExDKhw
3. Clipboard canvas (didn't work)

   https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/clipboard.htm
4. Plotchart using Saveplot (need gs(gost scripts), I will not use it, Saved .ps file is success)

   [How to save Plotchart canvas other than PostScript without displaying it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330242/how-to-save-plotchart-canvas-other-than-postscript-without-displaying-it)

I think, fixing img clipping trouble is easiest way for me.

### Output so far

Canvas convert file format:
[image: canvas convert file format Sample]

Using snapshot and convert file format:
[image: using snapshot and convert file format Sample]

Original graph:
[image: original graph]

Comment: @L. Alejandro M. Anything ok ( canvas copy, canvas to img File).

And main problem is these ways are occured clipping problem. (error code is none)

See above Sample img.  #original graph is completed by my code.

Comment: self answer : I have too old "img" tcl lib. When I've update and running program, has no problem. Thanks too read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save your canvas to image, may be this example help you:

`package require Img
pack [canvas .c -height 50 -width 50]
.c create rectangle 0 0 25 25 -fill blue
.c create rectangle 25 25 50 50 -fill green
raise . ;# if there's anything over the window on-screen, it'll be obscured in the image
update idletasks
image create photo theCanvas -format window -data .c
theCanvas write "C:\\your\\path\\here\\example.png" -format png`

(Note: the line of update isn't in the original)

Credit: [Mike Griffiths in tcl wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1415#pagetoccaeec76a)

Saludos,